# Visual Web Developer 2008 question

Tags: visual-studio

Could you please explain the following two questions about Visual Web Developer 2008?

1) Will it work if I have only .Net 3.0

2) Can it work even if there is Visual Studio 2005 is installed?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It download the framework 3.5 during the installation if you don't have it
2) Yes, no compatibility problems!

Answer (score 0):

In short:

1 - Yes

2 - Yes